# Russian vs Latin

Tags: этимология

1. Is **дом** an import from Latin *domus* as a loanword, or is it the byproduct of the common indo-european substratum?
2. In my country, on the façade of courts, it's written DOMUS IUSTITIÆ, "the house of justice". If translated literally into Russian, it could become **"Дом Юстиции"**, perhaps.

   In **юстиция**, the Latin root is evident, since words of Slavic origin related to justice, righteousness or fairness contain the root **право**.

   However, my question is, **юстиция** may only be used as a juridic term referring to the institution of law and court, whereas **справедливость**, which is the Slavic equivalent of *iustitia*, is required for the remaining shades of meaning of the word "justice" in English, right?
3. May **огонь** be related to Latin *ignis*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look up word origin in an [etymology dictionary](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C). I found [this one](https://gufo.me/dict/krylov?letter=%D0%B0) easy enough for beginners (it provides links to other dictionaries including [Vasmer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Vasmer)).

1. **Дом** is of Indo-European origin and related to Latin *domus*
2. Yes. **Юстиция** is used as juridic term only. It has a synonym of Russian origin - **правосудие**. "House of justice" will most probably translate to 
   **дом/дворец правосудия**. **Справедливость** means *fairness* and is used in less formal contexts and **честность** is an informal word for this.
3. [Yes](https://gufo.me/dict/krylov/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C).

Comment: "Справедливость" is not a "formal" synonym for "честность" (in most contexts). Rather, "честность" is personal, and "справедливость" is non-personal (with respect to authority that decides the outcome). People typically comment on "честность - нечестность" of decisions of individuals (judges, magistrates) and on "справедливость - несправедливость" of laws and divine acts.